# basicHttpBinding authentication error

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, basichttpbinding

I am new on web services and I need to implement `basicHttpBinding` to an existing web service with `wsHttpsBinding` and `basicHttpBinding` for a C# desktop application. When I try to consume the service with the desktop application I get the following error:

> The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.

The web.config file on the web service with the `basicHttpBinding` and the `wsHttpsBinding` looks like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<diagnostics>
  <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true"
    logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
    maxMessagesToLog="25000">
    <filters>
      <clear />
    </filters>
  </messageLogging>
</diagnostics>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="SecureBehave">
      <serviceCredentials>
        <clientCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust"/>
        </clientCertificate>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="HIBridgeLib.HIBridgeService.Security.MessageSecurityValidator, HIBridgeLib"/>
        <!--
        <serviceCertificate findValue="WCfServer"
          storeLocation="CurrentUser"
          storeName="My"
          x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
        -->
      </serviceCredentials>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="HIBridge_SSLBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" negotiateServiceCredential="True" establishSecurityContext="True" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>

  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="HIBridge_BasicBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
      </security>
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<services>
  <service name="HIBridgeWebService.HIBridgeService" behaviorConfiguration="SecureBehave">
    <endpoint address="basic" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="HIBridge_BasicBinding" contract="HIBridgeLib.HIBridgeService.IHIBridgeService"></endpoint>
    <endpoint address="ws" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="HIBridge_SSLBinding" contract="HIBridgeLib.HIBridgeService.IHIBridgeService"></endpoint>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="https://10.50.1.85:1125/HIBridge/HIBridgeService.svc" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```

The userNameAuthentication looks like this:

```
namespace HIBridgeLib.HIBridgeService.Security
{
  public class MessageSecurityValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
  {
     private const string USERNAME = "username";
     private const string PASSWORD = "password";

     public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
     {
        if (userName == null || password == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        if (USERNAME.Equals(userName) && PASSWORD.Equals(password))
        { 
        }
        else
        {    
            throw new FaultException("Invalid Message Security Credentials");
        }
    }
  }
}
```

And my desktop application code looks like this to consume the web service:

```
ChannelFactory<HIBridgeLib.HIBridgeService.IHIBridgeService> myChannelFactory = null;
HIBridgeLib.HIBridgeService.IHIBridgeService HIBridgeService = null;
System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding basicHTTPBinding = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding();

basicHTTPBinding.Name = "HIBridge_BasicBinding";
basicHTTPBinding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
basicHTTPBinding.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
basicHTTPBinding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
basicHTTPBinding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
basicHTTPBinding.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;                
basicHTTPBinding.HostNameComparisonMode = System.ServiceModel.HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard;
basicHTTPBinding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483647;
basicHTTPBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;
basicHTTPBinding.MessageEncoding = System.ServiceModel.WSMessageEncoding.Text;
basicHTTPBinding.TextEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
basicHTTPBinding.UseDefaultWebProxy = true;
basicHTTPBinding.AllowCookies = false;
basicHTTPBinding.Security.Mode = System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
basicHTTPBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = System.ServiceModel.HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
basicHTTPBinding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = System.ServiceModel.HttpProxyCredentialType.None;
basicHTTPBinding.Security.Transport.Realm = "";

System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress endpointAddress = null;

if (LocalMedCart.CartProfile.ConsoleHostname.Contains("/HIBridge/HIBridgeService.svc"))
      endpointAddress = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(LocalMedCart.CartProfile.ConsoleHostname + "/basic");
else
      endpointAddress = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(string.Format("https://{0}:{1}/HIBridge/HIBridgeService.svc/basic", LocalMedCart.CartProfile.ConsoleHostname, LocalMedCart.CartProfile.CommunicationPort));

HIBridgeLib.HIBridgeService.Security.PermissiveCertificatePolicy.Enact(string.Format("CN={0}", LocalMedCart.CertificateName));

myChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<HIBridgeLib.HIBridgeService.IHIBridgeService>(basicHTTPBinding, endpointAddress);
myChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
HIBridgeService = myChannelFactory.CreateChannel();

//do something

((IClientChannel)HIBridgeService).Close();
myChannelFactory.Close();
```

What is causing the error?

Comment: Not sure it's the issue, but your web service config says `security mode="Transport"` in the basicHttpBinding, but your client code uses `Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are specifically targeting the `basicHttpBinding` of the service.  So, the `wsHttpBinding` settings are irrelevant, as is the `MessageSecurityValidator` class.  In general, your client-side settings should match the server-side settings, which use `transport` security *with a client credential certificate*.  The user will be identified by this certificate as far as WCF is concerned.  So, instead of trying to set a username, you need to ensure that you are using a valid, server-recognized certificate.  Unfortunately, I do not have quite enough information to troubleshoot exactly what is wrong with your certificate, but check that:

1. Your local certificate store (on the machine running the desktop application) actually has a certificate that the service recognizes as valid.
2. The certificate is specified correctly.  [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731074(v=vs.110).aspx) suggests something along the lines of [`myClient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576346(v=vs.110).aspx) to provide the certificate.  (The example service in the link uses `wsHttpBinding` rather than `basicHttpBinding`, but for this aspect of configuration, it should make no difference.)
3. The web server hosting the service is actually configured for client certificate authentication.  [One reference](https://blogs.iis.net/rickbarber/archive/2013/09/04/require-client-certificates-in-iis-7-5.aspx) suggests checking the output of `netsh http show sslcert` at an administrator command prompt on the web server to see whether Negotiate Client Certificate is enabled for the site.

Comment: Andrew thank you for your reply, you were right I did not have the local certificate set correctly. Is there a way that I can consume the service with just a server side certificate?

Comment: The certificate has to be on both the client and the server anyway. As long as the certificate meets IIS requirements for this task, I don't know that it matters. You are probably better off just creating a self-signed certificate and installing it on your client and server, at least if this is an internal app.